# Сопоставление трёх списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Имеется 3 списка:

```
a = [12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1]
b = [20, 21, 22, 23, 200, 201, 202]
c = ['04-04', '05-05', '06-06', '07-07', '008-008', '009-009', '100-100']
```

Требуется для уникального значения из `a` вывести сопоставление из `b`, `c` равное количеству повторений значений `a`, т.е.:

uid=12

- 20 04-04
- 21 05-05
- 22 06-06
- 23 07-07

uid=1

- 200 008-008
- 201 009-009
- 202 100-100

вывод уникальных значений из `a`:

```
    for i in range(0, len(list(set(a)))):
        print('uid=' + str(sorted(set(a), key=a.index)[i]))
    >>> uid=12
    >>> uid=1
```

количество повторяющихся элементов в `a`:

```
for i in range(0, len(list(set(a)))):
    print(a.count(sorted(set(a), key=a.index)[i]))
>>> 4
>>> 1
```

сопоставление `b` и `c`:

```
x = []
for j, o in zip(b, c):
    x.append(str(j) + ':' + o)
print(x)
>>> ['20:04-04', '21:05-05', '22:06-06', '23:07-07', '200:008-008', '201:009-009', '202:100-100']
```

Дальше ступор, как сопоставить ума не приложу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При условии, что повторяющиеся элементы идут подряд и больше не встречаются:

```py
from collections import Counter

a = [12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1]
b = [20, 21, 22, 23, 200, 201, 202]
c = ['04-04', '05-05', '06-06', '07-07', '008-008', '009-009', '100-100']

result = {}
start = 0
stop = 0

for key, value in Counter(a).items():
  start = stop
  stop = start + value

  result[key] = list(zip(b[start:stop], c[start:stop]))

print(result)
```

Comment: `result[key] = dict(zip(b[start:stop], c[start:stop]))` и `for k, v in result.items():
    print('uid: ', k, 'message: ', v)`  то что требовалось

Answer (score 4):

```py
In [1]: a = [12, 12, 12, 12, 1, 1, 1]
   ...: b = [20, 21, 22, 23, 200, 201, 202]
   ...: c = ['04-04', '05-05', '06-06', '07-07', '008-008', '009-009', '100-100']

In [2]: result = {}

In [3]: for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c):
   ...:     result.setdefault(x, []).append((y, z))  # Группируем
   ...:

In [4]: for key, values in result.items():  # Выводим
   ...:     print(f"uid={key}")
   ...:     for y, z in values:
   ...:         print(f" - {y} {z}")
   ...:
```

Вывод:

```
uid=12
 - 20 04-04
 - 21 05-05
 - 22 06-06
 - 23 07-07
uid=1
 - 200 008-008
 - 201 009-009
 - 202 100-100
```

Comment: В строке "Группируем" лучше написать `result.setdefault(x, []).append((y, z))`

Comment: @вася Ух ты, спасибо) Никогда не пользовался этим методом, буду знать. Ответ отредактировал.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

for elem in (np.unique(a)):
    print(elem)
    for i in [x[0] for x in np.argwhere(np.array(a)==elem)]:
        print(f"\t{b[i]}", end="")
        print(f"\t{c[i]}")
```

получим:

```
1
    200 008-008
    201 009-009
    202 100-100
12
    20  04-04
    21  05-05
    22  06-06
    23  07-07
```